# Ideal order and structure of routine?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle-gain, muscle-mass

Some of the routines I've had have multiple muscles in the same day. For example: Day 1 has Chest, Back, Biceps and Shoulders while Day 3 has Triceps, Legs, Chest and Shoulders

I'm currently trying to improve and gain mass. I'm 68kg, 175cm and I've been working out for almost two years.

Maybe it's just my opinion, but don't the routines have to focus on max 2 muscles? For example Day 1 would be Biceps and Chest? Since I'm trying to stimulate those specific parts to make them stronger and increase (or make them bigger)

And coming to that, is there some way to do this in a optimal order? For example is it more recommended to work biceps and triceps together rather than biceps with chest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singular ideal for physical fitness simply doesn’t exist.

There are various viable strategies for the structure of a training program. Among the more popular are the Bro Split, Push/Pull/Legs, and Full Body routines. Exercise selection and timing within the week can vary drastically (even within the same split) as different goals will inevitably require different roads to get there.

There are however certain constants which function as a sort of foundation for fitness routines. Those being stimuli and rest. By balancing how much stimuli is beneficial before it becomes detrimental along with how much recovery time is necessary without being excessive, a fitness routine can take many forms (including those already mentioned).

You may find that you like and respond better to a certain way of doing things, but variety is important too. If your body completely adapts to something, then that something will no longer require your body to adapt. I’m not suggesting to do a different program every week or even every month, but switching things up a few times a year can help your body to continually improve. It’s perfectly fine to have a favorite that you always come back to, but don’t be afraid to try new things.

Comment: Then it all depends on how my body react and if it gives an plus to it?

Comment: To a certain degree. Most competent routines are going to benefit most of the people doing them (correctly). A really good program will benefit almost anyone. However, not all programs are good or competent so while it's something to consider, I don't think it's a problem in your case. The way in which muscle groups are split doesn't make it good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

Some common muscle pairings:

Chest and triceps - Triceps are often paired with chest day. Do chest first with compound movements like presses. Then finishing with some isolation tricep work. Since the triceps get worked during most chest exercises, it just goes naturally to finish them off on the same day.

Back and biceps - Same idea as chest/triceps, since biceps are worked with almost every back lift it makes sense to finish them off with some isolations on the same day.

Legs - Legs include many muscles but are often just grouped in one "leg day". If you're only doing one leg day a week, then do only legs, but make sure you hit each muscle; glutes, hams, quads, calves, ...

Arms and shoulders - arms and shoulder ares a good match up too, but it's a little specialized. If you're a beginner or only working out a few days a week you would be better off adding a little shoulder work to back and chest days, and split bicep/triceps as described above.

There are a variety of ways to break up your lifts and the perfect split is constantly up for debate. Push-pull-legs is another popular split, maybe someone else will address that.

Comment: You mean by specialized meaning that u will need like a good level already to do specific exercises?

Comment: Maybe "targeted" is a better word. Basically, it's not a lot of bang for your buck. So unless you need very targeted exercises because you're very progressed, or you just have time to spend on isolation lifts, its not worth setting aside a day for this smaller group of muscles, that are already working as secondary muscles for bigger lifts